# angularjs2 trying to create custom pipes

Tags: angular

New to angularjs2 Trying to create custom pipe in angularjs2 getting error

ReferenceError: Pipe is not defined" "Report this error at https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues"

//app.ts

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Box} from './components/box/box';
import { currentIndexPipe } from './pipes/currentIndex.Pipe';
import {approvedPrayers} from './services/approvedPrayers';


@Component({
    selector: 'app',   
     viewBindings: [approvedPrayers],


})

@View({
    templateUrl: './app.html',
    directives:  [Box],


})
class App {
}


bootstrap(App, [routerInjectables]);
```

//box.ts

```
import {Component, View,NgFor,Pipe,PipeTransform} from 'angular2/angular2';
import { approvedPrayers } from '../../services/approvedPrayers';
import { currentIndexPipe } from '../../pipes/currentIndexPipe';


@Component({
    selector: 'prayerbox'
})




@View({
        templateUrl: './components/box/box.html?v=<%= VERSION %>',
      directives: [NgFor],
pipes[currentIndexPipe]
})


export class Box {
 constructor(public list: approvedPrayers) {


    }


}
```

//currentIndexPipe.ts

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/angular2';






@Pipe({
    name: 'currentIndex',

})

export class currentIndexPipe implements PipeTransform {

 transform(value: number,status) {
     return Array[value];

  }
}
```

please help me figure this out please and thank you

Answer (score 0):

in *currentIndexPipe.ts* ,change your

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

to

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
```

Because angualr 2 team has change this property some time ago.
Fore more information please refer the [Pipe Documentation angualr 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)
Hope this helps.

Comment: if it didn't work,try to change the @angular to angualr2